# Why am I getting an infinite loop when using do-while loop with my print function

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a menu of different functions which supposed to run until the user inputs the 'Q' or 'q' character. When I try to run the program, it keeps on looping the default switch case. Am I using the wrong loop?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


bool getout{false};
char cases ;

void menu(){
cout << "\n\nP - Print Number\nA - Add Number\nM - Display mean of the number\nS - Display the smallest number\nL - -Display the largest number\nQ - Quit\n\nEnter your choice: " << endl;
}

char read(){
cin>> cases;
}

int main(){

do{

void menu();
void read();

switch (cases){
case 'p':
case 'P':  void print();
break;


case 'S':
case 's':
              void smallest();
break;

case'Q':
case 'q':
getout=true;
break;


default:
    cout<<"Please input a valid option";

}//switch braces
}
while (getout==false);

return 0;}
```

Comment: `void menu(); void read();` are function declarations, not calls. No code is executed, so the loop doesn't really do anything.

Comment: I think we need to subject you to a year of Python coding if you are refusing to indent your code.

Comment: You use a lot of function declarations instead of function calls (for example, `void menu();` instead of `menu();`, and please indent your code correctly

Comment: Thank you very much,I was declaring the functions instead of calling them. Thank you for your precious time

Comment: Why *wouldn't* it do that? It is doing what you told it to do.

Comment: @Bathsheba  your threat brings [flashbacks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qn1Yx1sojns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your read() function doesn't return anything in spite of being marked as returning a char. You call the function incorrectly in your main function as well. This is the main culprit.

Remove the word void.

I've attached a touched-up version of your code. It moves the global variables into the main function (globals are a thing to avoid whenever possible), and fixes the read function to return a character. I can never tell if the poor formatting in the question is a copy-paste issue, or your code is legitimately that sloppy, but in either case I also formatted it.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void menu() {
  std::cout
      << "\n\nP - Print Number\nA - Add Number\nM - Display mean of the "
         "number\nS - Display the smallest number\nL - -Display the largest "
         "number\nQ - Quit\n\nEnter your choice: ";
}

char read() {
  char choice;
  std::cin >> choice;

  return choice;
}

int main() {
  bool getout{false};

  do {
    menu();
    char cases = read();

    switch (cases) {
    case 'p':
    case 'P':
      void print();
      break;

    case 'S':
    case 's':
      void smallest();
      break;

    case 'Q':
    case 'q':
      getout = true;
      break;

    default:
      std::cout << "Please input a valid option";

    } // switch braces
  } while (getout == false);

  return 0;
}
```